# config.static_cache_control isn't setting cache-control in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, cache-control

I have a rails 4 application and I'm trying to set cache-control to true so images, css and js are cached by the browser. Everything I have read says to add the following to the production.rb file.

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
```

But it doesn't do anything. Cache-control is still set to `cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`. I cant find anything more that needs to be done for this to work.

Comment: Which Rails-Server do you use (unicorn/puma/...)? Do you use nginx or apache for content delivery?

Comment: @slowjack2k Well I don't really know actually... Never dealt with anything to do with them. Whatever the defaults are I guess. If that doesn't help how can I findout?

Comment: You can have look into your server response. Maybe there is a header `Server`. Are you still in development or is your  application deployed? All settings depend on your deployment setup.

Comment: The app is deployed. This is what I see for the server header `server: Google Frontend`

Comment: Your using `google app engine` as hosting provider. You should have a look into your `app.yml` . You should look for `handlers` or `* expiration` entries. It's not only a rails question. It's also a `google app engine`  question.

Comment: Ok thanks! I hope that pushes me in the right direction.

Comment: As far as I know `google app enginge` started in may 2016 with ruby support. So you will find documentions only sparsely.